# Sending an ipv4 packet to the Destination IP without a router?

Tags: routing, ipv4, networking

We are replacing a "RF modem + Router system" with a Software Defined Receiver.
After analyzing the receiving and sent signals we found out that an IPv4 UDP packets have been sent and received. 
 The packets have a source IP like: 192.1.168.225 and the destination IP changes (its sometimes 192.1.168.41 and sometimes broadcast 192.1.168.255) 
 Now the "Software Defined Receiver" is placed inside a PC. 
As we don't have a router anymore how can we send the obtained IP packets to the destination IP's or broadcast?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a router if the traffic is sent to IP's within the same subnet. As long as the subnet mask is the same for all hosts in the network they will listen to the broadcast IP and will respond to ARP requests.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I have the IP Packet inside the PC. Now how should I send it to the network? If I open a socket and send it it will add some overhead. In short,we don't know how to send it as it is programmaticaly.

Comment: I can't really help you with any custom software stuff, you would need to throw the packet into the tcp stack with something but it sounds like out of scope question for network engineering.

Comment: Is there something like a SW Router?

Comment: @Kurtul - there are SW routers, or you can just use a Linux box with IP forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a router to move traffic within the same subnet, that's all layer 2 transport with MAC addresses resolved with ARP.

There are software routers out there-- you could also use a small Linux VM to act as a basic router. You can check out a tutorial [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/enable_forwarding_of_ipv4_packets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Traffic will move between layer2 segment  only  if traffic is in same subnet  mac -address table is verified to destine traffic to destination .. whereas to move traffic in different subnet layer3 segment is taken into consideration ARP table and routing table plays key role to destine traffic to destination .

So make sure  your software define by you fallow required parameters at layer2 and layer3 segments.